# How to encrypt whole file using AES-256 encryption?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, encryption, aes

I have one SQL database file in my bundle. I need to encrypt that file using AES-256 and need to write this data to another file.

I have already tried to use RNCryptor and CryptoSwift as well but, I am to getting exact solutions for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read any file as `Data` or `NSData` instance and apply encryption to that and write back with a custom extensions may be.. You can use the lib suggested by @Ashish Rana or https://gist.github.com/hfossli/7165dc023a10046e2322b0ce74c596f8

1. Load data from file
   `guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file-to-be-encrypted", withExtension: "txt") else { return }`
   `guard let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) else { return }`
2. Apply encryption
   `let encrypted = try aes.encrypt(digest)`
3. Save encrypted file back
   `try encrypted.write(to: encURL)`

If you do not want to share the encrypted file and just want to secure it then you can use OS base encryption like mentioned here: https://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-encrypt-ios,news-18338.html

Comment: I need to share this file.

Answer (score 0):

Using both `AES256Crypter` and `Rijndael`, I got AES-256 encryption and decryption.

Add code from this link : https://github.com/superk589/RijndaelSwift

```
class StringCipher {

    static func Encrypt(plainText : String,  passPhrase : String) -> String {

        var result = ""
        let salt = AES256Crypter.randomSalt()
        let iv = AES256Crypter.randomSalt()

        let saltByte = [UInt8](salt)
        let ivByte = [UInt8](iv)
        do {
            let key = try AES256Crypter.createKey(password: passPhrase.data(using: .utf8)!, salt: salt)
            let r = Rijndael(key: key, mode: .cbc)!
            let decryptedData = r.encrypt(data: plainText.trimmed().data(using: .utf8)!, blockSize: 32, iv: iv)
            let dataBypte = [UInt8](decryptedData!)
            let mainByte = saltByte + ivByte + dataBypte
           // print(mainByte.count)

            let plainData = Data(bytes: mainByte)
            result = (plainData.base64EncodedString())
           // print(result)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed")
            print(error)
        }
        return result
    }
    static func Decrypt( cipherText : String,  passPhrase : String) -> String {

        var result = ""

        do {
            let bData = cipherText.data(using: .utf8)!
            if let nsData = NSData(base64Encoded: cipherText, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
                let bytes = [UInt8](nsData as Data)
               // print(bytes, String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8))
               // print(bytes.count)
                let subArray1 = bytes[0...31]
                let subArray2 = bytes[32...63]
                let subArray3 = bytes[64...(bytes.count-1)]

                let saltData = Data(bytes: subArray1)
                let ivData = Data(bytes: subArray2)
                let plainData = Data(bytes: subArray3)

               /*
                print("salt === \(saltData.base64EncodedString())\n\n")
                print("IV === \(ivData.base64EncodedString())\n\n")
                print("Data === \(plainData.base64EncodedString())\n\n")
                */

                let key = try AES256Crypter.createKey(password: passPhrase.data(using: .utf8)!, salt: saltData)
                print(key.count)

                let r = Rijndael(key: key, mode: .cbc)!

                let decryptedData = r.decrypt(data: plainData, blockSize: 32, iv: ivData)
              //  print("Original: \(String(decoding: decryptedData!, as: UTF8.self))")
                result = (String(decoding: decryptedData!, as: UTF8.self)).trimmed()

            }

        } catch {
            print("Failed")
            print(error)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't advice non-standard encryption algorithms. RIJNDAEL is not AES. It was a candidate for the AES competition and the winner. When AES has standardized it has differences from RIJNDAEL. RIJNDAEL can have 128+32*k-bit block sizes whereas AES has only 128-bit. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 has 256-bit block size, therefore, it is incompatible for AES.